# Hyperledger-Composer: not able to access javaScript split()-function from within transaction processor function

Tags: javascript, split, hyperledger-composer

In my hyperledger composer app I added some programmatic access control to a transaction processor function (in file logic.js).

One of the lines of code I added throws an error:

Here is the line of code:

```
for (consultantRef of transaction.newConsultants) {
   //the following line of code does NOT work:
   let consultantId = consultantRef.split('#')[1];
```

In the console I get the following error message:

```
"transaction returned with failure: TypeError: consultantRef.split is not a function"
```

---

For clarification:

transaction.newConsultants is an array of the following type:

["resource:org.comp.app.Consultant#id1",    "resource:org.comp.app.Consultant#id2",
    "resource:org.comp.app.Consultant#id3"]

I want to get the id of the respective consultants (e.g. "id1").

According to the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), the split function DOES exist.

But it doesn't work.

How can I get the ids of the consultants?

---

UPDATE:

When I look at the attributes of the transaction in the console, I see the following for the attribute "newConsultants":

```
newConsultants: Array (1)
0 "resource:org.comp.app.Consultant#john.doe@gmail.com_1535655902439"

Array Prototype
```

---

For clarification:
transaction is an object, namely the following (copied from the angular front-end):

```
 this.transaction = {
     $class: 'org.comp.app.AddToConsultantsOfProject',
     'project': 'resource:org.comp.app.project#' + this.projectId,
     'newConsultants': this.selectedConsultants,
     'timestamp': new Date().getTime()
 };
```

Comment: Can you log and share the `consultantRef` value inside loop

Comment: tried at my end, if the value of transaction.newConsultants is what you say, then it should work fine. can you print the transaction.newConsultants to be sure?

Comment: Is transaction an object or part of the name of the variable? I've inserted the newConsultants key into an object called transaction, and I get no such error message.

Comment: @Suresh Prajapati: I cannot log the value ... it's not possible to access the console from inside a hyperledger composer transaction processor function

Comment: @DKyleo: transaction is an object

Comment: split doesn't work because consultantRef is not a string, it will be a Resource object as they will have been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because its a Resource. You would likely convert it to a String (then split would be available on the string object - but you would still need to remove trailing characters (of the resource converted)).

There is a better way -try something like:

```
 trxn.newConsultants.forEach((consultantRef) => {
  console.log("identifier is " + consultantRef.getIdentifier());
  });
```

`getIdentifier()` is described in the Composer API docs.